# FTP over HTTPS remote server file Upload using WEBAPI

Tags: ssl, c#-4.0, https, asp.net-web-api2

I am facing issue with connecting FTP over HTTPS remote server and to upload file.
I have third party server which is **Hostgator** with Re-seller Account,Before SSL certificate, i Was uploading the file **using below code** which was working.I have purchase the SSL certificate.Now if i use same code to upload the file its not working giving me exception **System.Net.WebException** and **System error**.Kindly help to Upload file into remote server directory using FTP over HTTPS.

```
public string UploadImageURL(string ImageFileName, string ImageBase64, string UploadDirectory)
    {
        string ftpurl = "ftp://www.domain.com/";
        var username = "xxxxxx";
        var password = "aaaaaa";
        ImageFileName = "testing.jpeg";
        string UploadDirectory = "httpdocs/ImageFolder/";

         try
        {

            //string PureFileName = new FileInfo(VoiceModel.FileName).Name;
            if (ImageFileName != null && ImageBase64 != null)
            {
                String uploadUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", ftpurl, UploadDirectory, ImageFileName);
                FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
                req.Proxy = null;
                req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                req.EnableSsl = true;
                req.UseBinary = true;
                req.UsePassive = true;

                //Connect to SSL Port (990)
                ServicePoint sp = req.ServicePoint;
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(ImageBase64);
                req.ContentLength = data.Length;
                req.Timeout = -1;
                Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();
                FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
               ImageUrl = Convert.ToString(res.ResponseUri);
               ImageUrl = ImageUrl.Replace("ftp://", "http://");
               ImageUrl = ImageUrl.Replace("httpdocs/", "");
               ImageUrl = ImageUrl.Trim();
                return ImageUrl;
            }
            else
            {
                return ImageUrl = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can user Below Function for HTTPS, It's working fine

```
public string UploadFile(string Ext,string FtpUrl,string fileName,string userName,string password,string UploadDirectory,Stream inputstream,double NewWidth,double NewHeight)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(inputstream);
    Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    var newWidth = (int)(bmp.Width * NewWidth);
    var newHeight = (int)(bmp.Height * NewHeight);

    Bitmap bmpNew = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bmpNew);
    canvas.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0,
    bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height,
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    bmp = bmpNew;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    if (Ext == ".jpg" || Ext == ".jpeg")
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    else if (Ext == ".png")
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    else if (Ext == ".gif")
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
    else if (Ext == ".btm")
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
    else if (Ext == ".tiff")
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff);
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
    byte[] fileBytes = ms.ToArray();

    string PureFileName = new FileInfo(fileName).Name;
    FileInfo oFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
    String uploadUrl1 = String.Format("{0}{1}", FtpUrl, UploadDirectory);
    bool result = MFtpDirectoryExists(uploadUrl1, userName, password);
    String uploadUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", FtpUrl, UploadDirectory + "/", PureFileName);
    u.MsgBox(uploadUrl);
    FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    req.UseBinary = true;
    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Close();
    FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    return PureFileName;
}
```